# Can I distribute and install SQL Server Server Management Objects with my application?

Tags: sql-server, licensing, smo

For an application, I am building, I want to use SQL Server Managentment Objects.

**Am I allowed to distribute and install SMO DLL's with my application?**

The application requires a SQL Server installation (and therefore license), but not necessarily on the same server (ie my app on one PC, connecting to SQL Server on another).

After spending 30 minutes searching for the answer, I have found many - and contradicting - answers...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From MSDN, [Installing SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162189.aspx).

> To install the Client Tooks SDK without installing SQL Server, install Shared Management Objects from the SQL Server 2008 R2 [feature pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16978). If you want to ensure that SQL Server Management Objects is installed on a computer that will run your application, you can use the Shared Management Objects .msi in the feature pack.

Yes, you can install them, but you have to use the right installation vehicle, the .msi - I.e. don't just copy the assemblies from a machine with SQL Server installed.